# Output of Join operation in mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am performing a join operation in map reduce. I am giving in into two files with values separated by delimiter(comma). I am able to get in output in one file from both input file by performing the join operation on a common entity.

Here is the map reduce code:

```
public class EmpMapReduce {
public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>     
        {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException
                {
        String tokens [] = value.toString().split(",");
        String empid = tokens[0];
        String val = "";
        if(tokens.length != 0)
         {
            for (int cnt = 1; cnt < tokens.length; cnt++)
               {    
               val = val + tokens[cnt] + "\t";
            }
        }

        context.write(new Text(empid), new Text(val));

    }
   }

  public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
         {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
               {
            String str = "";
        for (Text val : values) 
                     {
            str = str + val.toString() + "\t";
         }

         context.write(key, new Text (str));

     }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args)
            .getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 3) {
        System.err.println("Usage: EmpMapReduce <in1> <in2> <out>");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = new Job(conf, "EmpMapReduce");



    job.setJarByClass(EmpMapReduce.class);

    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[2]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
   }
```

Here are two input file content I used:

```
100,name100,10
101,name101,11
102,name102,12
103,name103,13
104,name104,14
105,name105,15
106,name106,16
107,name107,17
```

Second input file:

```
100,100000
101,200000
102,300000
103,400000
104,500000
105,600000
106,700000
107,800000
```

I am getting following as output:

```
100,name100,10,100000
101,200000,name101,11
102,name102,12,300000
103,400000,name103,13
104,name104,14,500000
105,600000,name105,15
106,name106,16,700000
107,800000,name107,17
```

Now my concern is that why I am getting output like this:

```
100,name100,10,100000
101,200000,name101,11
```

that is in first row data is first copied from one input file and than from other. But for second row it is vice versa. I am not able to figure out how I can make the order of data same in every row.

Another question is :

Once I have data in all rows in a specific order than how I can perform various opertaions like : replacing name100 --->  somenewname  or  add at end of every row new comma seperated value having sum of all values previoulsy in that row.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the output from your two mappers arrives at the reducer is unspecified. So you need some way to identify them in the reducer.

A simple solution is to:

- have two mappers, one for each input
- each mapper outputs the value of "[type]:[rest of value]"
- say you have two types (users, transactions), now each is identified.
- now in your reducer (sorry for pseudo-code):

```
void reduce(..) {
  String user = "";
  String trans = "";

  for(value: values) {
    (type, payload) = value.split();
    if (type == "user") user = payload;
    if (type == "transaction") transaction = payload;
  }

  context.write(user + "\t" + transaction);
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the markdown thingy where you need to have a paragraph after the list for the following code block to display correctly, I've inserted an empty paragraph now and it looks good.

Comment: @MatthewRathbone: If I use two mappers for two inputs than I have to do something like that 'MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, path,                     inputFormatClass, mapperClass);' .So for this case I have to do overhead of overwriting the inputFormatclass. Is to complicated for this small problem. Correct me if I am thinking wrong and if yes please post a simple working solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2758929: I don't know what is wrong with formatting I tried my best to make the code indent and I see that you are more bother about formatting than  solution. but still thanks for pointing out that

Answer (score 0):

For Matthew's solution, you probably need to put this in the loop to wait for all the values being set in order to get the correct result:

```
if(!user.equals("") && !trans.equals("")){
       str = str + user+ "\t" + trans+ "\t";
}
```